# SASS: "Overflow: Scroll" Not working Possibly because of z-index [Followed Tutorial from DevTips]

Tags: scroll, sass, scrollbar, slidingmenu

I've been following DevTips tutorial on how to make a Sliding Sidebar with CSS. Basically long story short. The "page-content" class is what holds the actual website. I've put a box inside the page-content div named "main-content-box" which is display:flex. I have a header, main-content, and footer div's. The "main-content" has text in the form of Lorem Ipsum Paragraphs as placeholders.

Basically the page isn't scrolling. I dont know why. Maybe its because of my z-index... I'm not really sure how to describe whats going on. Here's my GitHub Repo on the matter. I've also attached the DevTips GitHub Repo as well as a guide/reference. I've modified the default files to include a background image as well. So it looks nice.

I've tried posting on the youtube tutorial video that DevTips released but no response. I put the Youtube Video inside the Git Repo.

Any help is appreciated. I'm new here so I'm sorry if i did something wrong or didn't provide enough information. :(

J. Robinson

My Documents
https://github.com/JDsWebService/StackOverflow_Question

DevTips Default Documents
https://github.com/DevTips/HTML-and-CSS-slide-out-navigation

Comment: The code you referenced is quite comprehensive. Could you provide a minimal example that represents your problem? See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I really can't. I dont know how i would provide a minimal example... This is a complex problem. Not something i can really explain in simple terms. Plus i read the link you provided and the code listed is literally all the code to re-create the problem. Nothing else is included... It's already minimized.

Comment: There are clearly still styles that have nothing to do with your problem (i.e. coloring). You could at least try to reproduce the problem on http://jsbin.com/ so people can fiddle with it right away.

Comment: Tried adding it on codepen and it wouldn't even display at ALL. So please just download the files and look at this via GitHub. I dont know whats going on. Seriously. Please this is already difficult enough for me and I dont know what to do already. You're making this more difficult then it has to be.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/zonurorura/edit?html,css,output

Still not displaying at ALL. Dont know what you want me to do from here.

Comment: import bourbon like this: @import 'bourbon/bourbon' Then we have a working solution - reference it prominently in your question and everybody can easily understand what your problem is.

Comment: @InMyHumbleOpinion I have updated the github repo to make it reflect the changes you suggested. I still cant figure out what the problem is. My website just will not scroll at all. I dont know why. Still needing help. Anyone? Please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was dealt with by checking the label with the .toggle class. It was taking up the entire screen. set a fixed width on the label and problem was solved.

Check repository here for more information and problem solution.

https://github.com/JDsWebService/StackOverflow_Question